# List index out of range for random cayley table

Tags: python, math

I'm trying to write a code to produce a random cayley table but I am getting a list index out of range error, I can't work out why.

Here is my code:

```
def randcaytab(n):
    if not n >= 0:
        return False
    table = []
    for i in range(n):
        table.append([])
        for j in range(n):
            for k in range(n):
                (table[j]).append(randint(0,(n-1)))
    return table
```

I get the error on this line:

```
(table[j]).append(randint(0,(n-1)))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
table[i].append(randint(0,n-1))
```

(the extra parenthesis didn't do any harm but they diminish readibility)